# Scrapy CrawlSpider Output while Crawling

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to learn Scrapy framework and I'm able to write a spider and crawl around the web and so forth. I'm also able to save the desired data but not in a way I would like to do.

Example Code:

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
    
    class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = 'examplecrawler'
        allowed_domains = ['example.com']
        start_urls = ['https://www.example/']
        rules = [
            Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True), follow=True, callback="parse")
        ]
    
        def parse(self, response):
            url = response.url
            yield {'link': url}
```

**Current Result:** Spider runs recursively and will only write output using Item Exporters when I stop it using **Control + C**

**Desired Result:** Spider runs recursively and write to output while running, not having to stop it to write output.

I have read through the documentation and see where I could possibly use something like writing a custom pipeline to write the data, but I was wondering if this was possible with the current item exporters. i.e.: csv and json.

Comment: Are you writing the output to an external storage system (e.g. S3, FTP, Google Storage)?  Otherwise, it should work as desired. See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/feed-exports.html#delayed-file-delivery

Comment: I'm using the feed exporters provided by scrapy, csv and json. I am not outputting to an external storage. I want to write it locally but don't want delayed output. i.e: if I ran the spider using scrapy runspider examplespider.py -o output.json, it only writes to output.json after I exit the spider with Control + C or after the spider has no more URL to crawl.

Comment: CSV output should work as you want; JSON is different, because it aims to keep the output file valid JSON, which means it has to write the whole file at once. Consider using JSON Lines instead, or subclass the exporter to work as you want.

Comment: I've tried JSON Lines and CSV but results is the same as JSON. Only thing that seems to work somewhat is setting FEED_EXPORT_BATCH_ITEM_COUNT in the settings but I don't want multiple files. I will give sqlite3 pipeline a try.

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify the way your current crawler works so it prints out it's real time status you will have to `modify the existing code of the base class or create a crawler yourself`. Since you are importing an existing module you really have no way of changing how it works so your best (if not only) bet is to create you own crawler with customized output.